# Обработка добавления нескольких тегов из POST-запроса

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Доброго времени суток,

Не могу сообразить, как правильно обработать POST-запрос с несколькими тегами.

Имеется POST-запрос из браузера на добавление книги, массив выглядит так:

```html
id:1
header: Kolobok
...:...//и т.д.
genre1: драмма
genre2: приключения
```

и т.д. неизвестное количество жанров(сколько выберет юзер).

Итак, на сервер (node.js) приходит этот массив и чтобы отправить в базу запрос на добавления вида:
INSERT INTO `genre` (`genre_id`), (`genre_id`), (`genre_id`)//и т.д, в зависимости от количество жанров

Нужно вытянуть из POST-а записи начинающиеся с genre и посчитать их количество.

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
  if (val == true)
   {console.log(val + ' -> ' + req.body[val]);}
});
```

Собственно вопрос, как сравнить val(это будет ключ) со строкой genre(1-20)?

И вообще, может есть способ попроще?

Comment: Хм, а зачем отправлять много схожих ключей? С формы можно вполне себе нормально отправить постом массив genre[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И вообще, может есть способ попроще?

Есть. На клиенте отсылать нормальный пост-запрос. И POST и GET поддерживают массивы, так что нет никакой проблемы в том, что бы отправлять POST-запрос вида:

```
genres[0]: приключения
genres[1]: фантастика
genres[2]: детектив
```

Потом, соответственно, доступ к элементам, как к обычному массиву

Если форму отправляете без использования JS, то в HTML такое достигается с помощью

```
<input name="genres[0]" value="приключения">
```

Если же отправляете форму через JS, то вопросов, я думаю, возникнуть особо не должно